# The boundary value of a bounded analytic function cannot vanish identically on any open subset of the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $g$ is a bounded function in the region $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C};Imz\le0\}$, analytic in the region $S
_0=\{z\in\mathbb{C};Imz\lt0\}$ and continuos on $S$.
Let $f$ be the boundary value of this function(i.e $g$ restricted to the real axis).

I need to conclude if  $f$ vanishes identically on any non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$,the $f$ is the trivial $0$ function.

I am not able to apply identity theorem because $g$ is not analytic on the real axis.
How should i conclude this?

I am basically going through the first part of proposition 3.1 in this paper
     http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1983-087-04/S0002-9939-1983-0687648-4/S0002-9939-1983-0687648-4.pdf

There are other things going on here but i believe i have posted the question with all requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is zero on an open interval $(a, b)$ then it follows from the
[Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle) that $g$
can be continued analytically to
$$
 \{z\in\mathbb{C} : \text{Im} \, z\lt0\} \cup (a, b) \cup \{z\in\mathbb{C} :\text{Im} \, z >0\}
$$
Now apply the identity theorem to the extended function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Schwarz reflection principle.  $\overline{g(\overline{z})}$ is analytic in the lower half plane, and has the same boundary value $f$ wherever $f$ is real.  By Morera's theorem, the combined function
$$ \cases{g(z) & for $\text{Im}(z) > 0$\cr
          \overline{g(\overline{z})} & for $\text{Im}(z) < 0$\cr
                0 & for $\text{Im}(z) = 0$\cr}$$
would be analytic, and therefore identically $0$.