# A complex analytic function vanishes on Angular area if vanishing on a line

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

Here is a question on my **complex analysis** textbook.

Let $f\in H\big(\{z\in \mathbb{C}:0<argz<\frac{\pi}{4}\}\big)$ and $f\in C^1\big(\overline{\{z\in \mathbb{C}:0<argz<\frac{\pi}{4}\}} \big)$. If $f\equiv 0 $ on $[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}^{+}$, then $f\equiv 0 $ on $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:0<argz<\frac{\pi}{4}\}$.

I think since the area is special, some integration formula is needed to derive the result. But I don’t know how.
Please give me some help and I’d be appreciate it.

Comment: You can proceed in the same way as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1675272/42969

Comment: Thanks. I can settle the question now.